# Ansible ini_file module: Replace whole section

Tags: ansible

As far as I understand the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ini_file_module.html), I can use the `ini_file` module to replace a whole section of an ini file by just specifying the `section` value and omitting the `option` value:

```
- name: 'Set realms'
  ini_file:
    path: '/etc/krb5.conf'
    section: 'realms'
    value: |
      EXAMPLE.COM = {
        admin_server = adm.example.com
        kdc = kdc.example.com
      }
```

which should result in

```
[realms]
EXAMPLE.COM = {
  admin_server = adm.example.com
  kdc = kdc.example.com
}
```

removing the original contents of section `[realms]`. However, this results in

```
[realms]
None = EXAMPLE.COM = {
  admin_server = adm.example.com
  kdc = kdc.example.com
}
```

while also not removing the original contents of the section.

Have I misunderstood the documentation? And if yes, is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: It's reported bug [ini_file doesn't handle multi-line entries #29711](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/29711) (no activity since Sept 2017).

Comment: Okay, that makes this module unusable for my case. However, it doesn't explain all of my results (like the `None = `).

Comment: It's buggy. I've [tested it](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-examples/blob/master/examples/example-102/play1.yml). In addition to the problem you reported, for example, if the file is empty no changes are written. If it's not empty I see the same problem as you. The bug report differs in attribute 'option' set, but I think it's not worth to open a new bug report because of this.

Comment: `ini` is an informal standard. The use of curly braces seems uncommon to me. Looking at the [code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/files/ini_file.py) I don't see an implementation for curly braces `{}`. I would recommend to write a Jinja2 template for that config file. That should give you a predictable result.

Answer (score 1):

@Rocreex actually you didn't define option key.

```yaml
- name: 'Set realms'
  ini_file:
    path: '/tmp/krb5.conf'
    section: 'realms'
    option: ' EXAMPLE.COM'
    value: | 
      ' {
         kdc = kerberos.example.com
         admin_server = kerberos.example.com
       } '
```